# Selector in css file for reactstrap component

Tags: css, reactstrap

**What do I want to achieve**

So there is a gap between my jumbotron and my footer. I want to remove that gap. I did it already successfully by setting the `margin-bottom` to 0px; But at that moment, I had to pass an ID to the Jumbotron element. Now I want to achieve that same effect without passing an ID, but with classes.

I don't want to use inline styles. I want it in a separate css file.

In an old library (**react-bootstrap not reactstrap**) I could select for example all components from a certain type, like I did in the css provided below.

So the mistake is probably the selector in the css file. I couldn't find anything online which specifically shows it in a seperate "css file" way. Only with inline styling.

**MainContent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './MainContent.css';
import { Jumbotron, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Container } from 'reactstrap';

const MainContent = () => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Jumbotron>
                <Form>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="exampleEmail">Email</Label>
                        <Input type="email" name="email" id="exampleEmail" placeholder="with a placeholder" />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="examplePassword">Password</Label>
                         <Input type="text" name="password" id="examplePassword" placeholder="password placeholder" />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <Button>Submit</Button>
                </Form>
            </Jumbotron>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default MainContent;
```

**MainContent.css**

```
.Container {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it with IDs or with inline-styling, there is a way I would call a hack.

In **MainContent.js** add `className` attribute to the component as follows:

```
<Jumbotron className="jumbotron">
```

And in **MainContent.css** add `!important` in the statement you want to override other stylings:

```
.Container {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Unless you override like this, `margin-bottom: 2rem` from **node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css** is used.

Comment: Okay but do you know how to achieve this, without specifying a class/id?